# using jQuery to change, only the elements that were loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

For each checkbox on the web page, I replace it with a slider that I borrowed from jsfiddle.net/gnQUe/170/

This is done by going through the elements when the document is loaded.

Now the problem is that when more content is loaded via ajax, the new checkboxes are not transformed.

To solve the problem, I used AjaxComplete event to go through all the elements again and replace the checkboxes with sliders.
Now the problem happens that elements that were already replaced, get two sliders. To avoid that I check if the checkbox is hidden and next element is div of class "slider-frame", then don't process the re-process the element.

But I have a lot of other such controls as well, and I am presume I am not the only one that has this problem. Is there another easy way around it?

There exists jQuery live/on( http://api.jquery.com/on/ ) event but it requires an event as an argument? whereas I would like to change the look of my controls when they are rendered.

Another example of the same problem is to extend some controls that are loaded via ajax with jQuerys autocomplete plugin.

Is there a better way to accomplish this other than changing some attributes on the element.

To summarize, on document load I would like to process every element in DOM, but when more elements are loaded via ajax then I want to change only the new elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that when the element's are transformed into a slider, a class is added to them. So just add a not clause.

```
$(".MySelector").not(".SomeClassThatSliderAddsToElement").slider({});
```

So in the case of your code do something like this

```
$('.slider-button').not(".sliderloaded").addClass("sliderloaded").toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass('on').html('YES');
    $('#slider').val(true);
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('on').html('NO');
    $('#slider').val(false);
});
```

Since you said you do not want to add anything else, how about you change the toggle function to click.

```
$(document).on("click", ".slider-button", function(){
   var elem = $(this);
   elem.toggleClass("on");
   var state = elem.hasClass("on");
   elem.text(state?"YES":"NO");
   elem.parent().next().val(state);    
});
```

Running fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d9uFs/

Comment: I was reffering to the same solution when I say "Is there a better way to accomplish this other than changing some attributes on the element."

I am only a few days old in the world of javascript, so I am looking for some auto-magical jQuery event that I am yet to discover.

Comment: Gave you another option which involves getting rid of toggle and using click. I also got rid of the reference to the hidden input. FYI: this control is not keyboard accessible.

Comment: Hi Erik,
I really appreciate your help. As I mentioned earlier that I am new to web programming so I am not ashamed to admit that I don't get the second suggestion. The problem is to add only one slider div for each checkbox no matter how may times I make ajax calls. And your first suggestion infact does solve the problem. But I assume that this is a fairly common issue and there may exist solutions built into jQuery to this problem.

Comment: There is nothing built into jQuery to do what you are asking. The second suggestion basically listens on the document for a click event. It checks to see if the element that triggered it has the class `slider-button` if it does it executes the code which does the same logic that was in your toggle code. The second way applies one event handler and will work with the dynamic elements that are added. There is no need to keep binding events.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will go with first suggestion i.e. to add a a class (e.g. sliderloaded) that the element has already been transformed to stop it from being transformed again.

Comment: Do you realize the second one does the same thing with no need to ever add the events?

Comment: Not really or perhaps we are not on the same page. Please have a look the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/hnTuk/. When I press the add new button, I would like to replace the checkboxes with sliders as soon as they are added.
What I want is that when new elements (checkboxes in this case) are added to the webpage, they are automatically replaced by the slider control and the sliders change the value of the checkbox they are replacing. If i dont add sliderloaded class and call the same code again in ajaxComplete event, all elements will be changed even the ones that are already changed.

Comment: It does not work because that event has NOTHING to do with the creation of the slider.The whole creation process is wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/hnTuk/1/